# C# WPF MaterialDesign In Xaml Toolkit DialogHost. The background window behind the dialog box is not darkened

Tags: wpf, xaml

The background window is not darkened when DialogHost is called, meaning the dialog is not modal. The back window remains active. Although in the Github example works correctly. I don't know where I'm going.

XAML:

```
        <materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="DH_getLoadingList" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        CloseOnClickAway="True"
        OverlayBackground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}" DialogTheme="Inherit" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="16" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="The row will be deleted." FontSize="16" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="OK" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsDefault="True" Margin="0,8,8,0"  />
                    <Button Content="Cancel" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Margin="0,8,8,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

C# code:

```
    private void GettingFuelListCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DH_getLoadingList.IsOpen = true;                
    }
```

**UPDATED**

I just had a misunderstanding the DialogHost structure. The correct way is

```
<Window>
    <materialDesign:DialogHost>
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
          <--! dialog content ... -->
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        
        <--! the correct location of the page content ... -->
        
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
    
    <--! incorrect location of the page content ... -->
    
<Window/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than a year late. But when you put these properties:

```
 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
 VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

The overlay background will not appear, if you remove these, the problem will go away. The dialog will always be centered so don't need to worry about it's relative position to it's parent container.